# Rowcount for all tables by year in dbo schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm looking for a query in SQL Server that will return the total number of rows for a given year across all tables in a particular schema, in this case `dbo`.

All tables in this schema have a column named `UPDT_TS` which stores the last time the row was updated and can be used for this date calculation.

Comment: You will have to make a procedure to go through  `information_schema.tables` getting all tables of that schema then count the rows grouped by a extracted year and sum it all.

Comment: How many tables are we talking about here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple cursor, and dynamic SQL.

```
declare @v_Year int
set @v_Year = 2013

declare @v_TableName nvarchar(256)
declare @v_SQL nvarchar(max)
declare @v_Count int

declare @v_ResultTable table
(
    TableName nvarchar(256),
    [RowCount] int
)

declare cur cursor local fast_forward read_only for
select t.name from sys.tables as t
inner join sys.columns as c on t.object_id = c.object_id
where c.name = 'UPDT_TS' and t.schema_id = schema_id('dbo')

open cur

while (1=1)
begin

    fetch next from cur into @v_TableName

    if @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
        break;

    set @v_SQL = 'select @v_Count = count(*) from '+QUOTENAME(@v_TableName)+' where year(UPDT_TS) = ' + cast(@v_Year as nvarchar(4))

    exec sp_executesql @v_SQL, N'@v_Count int output', @v_Count output

    insert into @v_ResultTable
    select @v_TableName, @v_Count

end

close cur
deallocate cur

select * from @v_ResultTable
```

**EDIT**
Just saw Goat's answer after posting :) looks like we hade the same idea :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a Results table to insert records into, you can do this with a simple cursor:

```
DECLARE  @Iterator varchar(255)
        ,@strSQL varchar(MAX) 

DECLARE xyz CURSOR CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT t.name
FROM  sys.schemas s
JOIN  sys.tables  t
  ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE s.name = 'dbo'

OPEN xyz 
FETCH NEXT FROM xyz 
INTO @Iterator     
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SET @strSQL = 'INSERT INTO Results
           SELECT COUNT(*) as Rows, '''+@Iterator+''' as TableName
           FROM '+QUOTENAME(@Iterator)+'
           WHERE YEAR(UPDT_TS) = 2013          
           '
EXEC (@strSQL)

    FETCH NEXT FROM xyz 
    INTO @Iterator 
END   
CLOSE xyz 
DEALLOCATE xyz 
GO
```

Whenever dealing with dynamic sql it can be helpful to change `EXEC (@strSQL)` to `PRINT (@strSQL)` to ensure you've got the syntax nailed down.

Comment: hahah...thanks ... i didnt think that edit looked quite right with the column aliases. (+1)

Comment: I like the usage of `QUOTENAME` use it with `FOR XML PATH` frequently but don't think of it elsewhere.  Didn't mean to delete the `CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY` but I don't think it would make any difference in this situation.

Comment: It wouldn't but I just put it in as a matter of habit

Answer (score 0):

This will work also:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)
,@year INT

SET @year = 2013

SELECT @sql = 'select sum (total) from (' + SUBSTRING(cast((
            SELECT ' union select count(*) as Total 
                from ' + quotename(table_name) + ' 
                where 
                    UPDT_TS between dateadd(year,@year-1900,0) and dateadd(s,-1,dateadd(year,@year-1900+1,0))'
            FROM information_schema.columns
            WHERE column_name = 'UPDT_TS'
                AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
            FOR XML path('')
            ) AS NVARCHAR(max)), 8, 8000) + ') as Presum'

PRINT @sql

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
,N'@year int'
,@year = @year
```